# Would after will/ will after would

Tags: grammar

Can you say "you'll hurt me more if you wouldn't."

If the person wouldn't do this thing they talk about now, in the future it will hurt the person more- you know for a fact that it'll hurt.

Another example: if you wouldn't take care of this now it will get worse

Comment: We don't normally say things like *if you wouldn't [do something]* - in nearly all contexts we'd say *if you **don't/won't** do it.* You could contrive a "conditional past tense" context, such as *If you wouldn't pay the entrance fee, it's not surprising they wouldn't/didn't let you go in,* but it's not common.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the conditional in the wrong place. I wouldn't say "you'll hurt me more if you wouldn't". I'd say "you would [you'd] hurt me more if you didn't."